# glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, calling-convention

When compiling below code:

```
global main
extern printf, scanf

section .data
   msg: db "Enter a number: ",10,0
   format:db "%d",0

section .bss
   number resb 4

section .text
main:
   mov rdi, msg
   mov al, 0
   call printf

   mov rsi, number
   mov rdi, format
   mov al, 0
   call scanf

   mov rdi,format
   mov rsi,[number]
   inc rsi
   mov rax,0
   call printf 

   ret
```

using:

```
nasm -f elf64 example.asm -o example.o
gcc -no-pie -m64 example.o -o example
```

and then run

```
./example
```

it runs, print: **enter a number:**
but then crashes and prints:
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

So printf works fine but scanf not.
What am I doing wrong with scanf so?

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger like gdb to let it tell you what instruction that caused the fault?

Comment: You have a potential issue with the stack not being aligned to a 16-byte boundary before calling the _C_ library routines (per the AMD64 ABI). `mov rsi,[number]` moves 8 bytes from number to RSI, when `number` is 4 bytes. Maybe you wanted `mov esi,[number]`

Comment: @Michael Petch - no, I am newbie to linux and assembler and gdb frighten me. But below code is an example from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889692/nasm-x86-64-scanf-segmentation-fault   and is marked as solution, so should works

Comment: Just because an answer is accepted doesn't mean it doesn't have problems. What happens if you add `push rbp` right after `main:` and just before `ret` add `pop rbp` (this should deal with the alignment issue). Change `mov rsi,[number]` to `mov esi,[number]` . GDB or any debugger is the ideal tool. If a debugger scares you, assembly is probably not what you should be programming in.

Comment: push rbp and pop rbp resolves problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) 64bit

Comment: Isn't the edb debugger is now available in the universe repositories of 18.04? Check it out, it has probably somewhat simpler UI, although it's not as powerful and versatile as gdb. If you are planning just to learn assembly basics with short pieces of code, edb should be sufficient for that. (if it's not in repos yet, you would have to compile it from source [from github], but that's not completely trivial either).

Answer (score 18):

**Use `sub rsp, 8` / `add rsp, 8` at the start/end of your function** to re-align the stack to 16 bytes before your function does a `call`.

Or better push/pop a dummy register, e.g. `push rdx` / `pop rcx`, or a call-preserved register like RBP you actually wanted to save anyway.  **You need the total change to RSP to be an odd multiple of 8 counting all pushes and `sub rsp`,** from function entry to any `call`.
i.e. `8 + 16*n` bytes for whole number `n`.

On function entry, RSP is 8 bytes away from 16-byte alignment because the `call` pushed an 8-byte return address.  See [Printing floating point numbers from x86-64 seems to require %rbp to be saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097173/printing-floating-point-numbers-from-x86-64-seems-to-require-rbp-to-be-saved),
[main and stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866723/main-and-stack-alignment), and [Calling printf in x86_64 using GNU assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335212/calling-printf-in-x86-64-using-gnu-assembler).  This is an ABI requirement which you used to be able to get away with violating when there weren't any FP args for printf.  But not any more.

See also [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment)

To put it another way, **`RSP % 16 == 8` on function entry, and you need to ensure `RSP % 16 == 0` before you `call` a function**.  How you do this doesn't matter.  (Not all functions will actually crash if you don't, but the ABI does require/guarantee it.)

---

**gcc's code-gen for glibc `scanf` (and more recently `printf`) now depends on 16-byte stack alignment even when `AL == 0`**.

It seems to have auto-vectorized copying 16 bytes somewhere in `__GI__IO_vfscanf`, which regular `scanf` calls after spilling its register args to the stack<sup>1</sup>.  (The many similar ways to call scanf share one big implementation as a back end to the various libc entry points like `scanf`, `fscanf`, etc.)

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04's libc6 binary package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libc6/download and extracted the files (with `7z x blah.deb` and `tar xf data.tar`, because 7z knows how to extract a lot of file formats).

I can repro your bug with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/bionic-libc/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ./bad-printf`, and also it turns out with the system glibc 2.27-3 on my Arch Linux desktop.

With GDB, I ran it on your program and did `set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /tmp/bionic-libc/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` then `run`.  With `layout reg`, the disassembly window looks like this at the point where it received SIGSEGV:

```
   │0x7ffff786b49a <_IO_vfscanf+602>        cmp    r12b,0x25                                                                                             │
   │0x7ffff786b49e <_IO_vfscanf+606>        jne    0x7ffff786b3ff <_IO_vfscanf+447>                                                                      │
   │0x7ffff786b4a4 <_IO_vfscanf+612>        mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x460]                                                                             │
   │0x7ffff786b4ab <_IO_vfscanf+619>        add    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x458]                                                                             │
   │0x7ffff786b4b2 <_IO_vfscanf+626>        movq   xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x460]                                                                            │
   │0x7ffff786b4ba <_IO_vfscanf+634>        mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x678],0x0                                                                             │
   │0x7ffff786b4c4 <_IO_vfscanf+644>        mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x608],rax                                                                             │
   │0x7ffff786b4cb <_IO_vfscanf+651>        movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rbx+0x1]                                                                                │
   │0x7ffff786b4cf <_IO_vfscanf+655>        movhps xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x608]                                                                            │
  >│0x7ffff786b4d6 <_IO_vfscanf+662>        movaps XMMWORD PTR [rbp-0x470],xmm0                                                                          │
```

So it copied two 8-byte objects to the stack with `movq` + `movhps` to load and `movaps` to store.  But with the stack misaligned, `movaps [rbp-0x470],xmm0` faults.

I didn't grab a debug build to find out exactly which part of the C source turned into this, but the function is written in C and compiled by GCC with optimization enabled.  GCC has always been allowed to do this, but only recently did it get smart enough to take better advantage of SSE2 this way.

---

Footnote 1: printf / scanf with `AL != 0` has always required 16-byte alignment because gcc's code-gen for variadic functions uses test al,al / je to spill the full 16-byte XMM regs xmm0..7 with aligned stores in that case.  `__m128i` can be an argument to a variadic function, not just `double`, and gcc doesn't check whether the function ever actually reads any 16-byte FP args.

Comment: Very interesting. openSuSE has no problem without alignment (gcc 4.8.5), but Arch indeed SegFaults (gcc 8.1.1). Insuring 16-byte alignment works fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: It was only very recently that this changed on Arch.

Comment: PS: `jmp scanf` to tail-call (like call scanf/ret) of course requires that RSP%16==8 instead of being aligned, to replicate the expected function-entry layout.  And as always, a jmp tailcall only works when RSP is pointing at your own return address, so scanf will get that return address.  So you can only tail-call it from a function that was itself called with 16-byte RSP alignment.

Answer (score 0):

As above, I traced down the offending instruction as:

```
0x7ffff7e4adcd <_IO_str_init_static_internal+61>:    movaps %xmm0,(%rsp)
```

Inside of glibc, in strops.c. Its doing a 128 bit move to the stack.

After fixing my stack alignments, I found that on entry to main:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x721a: file test.s, line 145.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/samiam/projects/pascal/pascal-p6/test

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.s:145
(gdb) i r
rax            0x55555555b21a      93824992260634
rbx            0x55555555b290      93824992260752
rcx            0x555555592860      93824992487520
rdx            0x7fffffffdf48      140737488346952
rsi            0x7fffffffdf38      140737488346936
rdi            0x1                 1
rbp            0x0                 0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffde48      0x7fffffffde48
...
```

The gcc generated startup passes control to my program with a stack that isn't aligned to 16 bytes!

I used the aligner:

```
andq    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
```

This appears wasteful, but realize that the stack must be 64 bit aligned by definition, so this is either going to dump 0 or 64 bits of stack on entry.

A call instruction is going to place 8 bytes on the stack (the rip), which means that a call is going to inherently UN-align the stack as far as the 16 byte requirement. This (in gcc) is fixed by the framing sequence:

```
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
```

Because the push is going to even up the stack to 16 bytes.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI - section 3.2.2 The Stack Frame - *In other words, the stack needs to be 16 (32
or 64) byte aligned immediately before the call instruction is executed.*  (The higher alignments only apply if there are `__m256` or `__m512` stack args, but the 16-byte requirement applies always, even with no stack args, input argument area of size 0 but still aligned.)  The ABI also spells out the implication that on function entry (after `call` pushes a return address), *`(%rsp + 8)` is a multiple of 16.*

Comment: IE, call+entry framing = 16 byte alignment. I modified my note to show this, thanks. It might be added "who cares?". This would be assembly language writers or compiler makers (I am the latter).

Comment: Well yes, those are the two usual suspects for people who care about most of an ABI standard. :P  Your answer still starts of wrongly saying that stack alignment requirements are a glibc thing; don't just add a correction later, edit to say the right thing in the first place.

Comment: Also, did you read my answer to this question?  Stack alignment on function entry has `RSP % 16 == 8`, so an odd number of pushes plus stack slot reservations with `sub` gets RSP ready for another call.  You don't need `and` unless you have callers that use a less-aligned version of the ABI.  (Like GCC will do with  `__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))`)  Treating incoming alignment as unknown makes it inconvenient to not use a frame pointer.

Comment: Your answer claims GCC always uses `push %rbp` / `mov %rsp, %rbp`, but that's only in un-optimized ("debug") builds.  The default at `-O1` and higher is `-fomit-frame-pointer`.  But many functions also want to save an even number of call-preserved registers (often including RBP), so they often need a dummy `push`, or an odd multiple of 8 in a `sub $imm, %rsp`.

Comment: GCC's default is `-O0`, no optimization.  Not a good example for efficient code-gen.  https://godbolt.org/z/8TTW6qx8j shows normal efficient asm from an optimized build vs. the mess of store/reload and a useless stack-frame setup we get from `-O0`.  The version that can't tail-call printf does have to `sub $8, %rsp` to realign the tack.  (Clang prefers to use a dummy `push %rax` because that's actually about as cheap as `sub $8, %rsp`, and cheaper in some cases on modern CPUs, and smaller code-size.)

Comment: I tend to avoid anything with constants, since putting the constant in the instruction, especially 64 bits, is more expensive than a register instruction. So I track the stack with a counter and issue push/pops to align. The andq with constant thing to align the frame is a catch-all align. Its pure laziness I agree.

Comment: `sub $8, %rsp` is a 4-byte instruction, including the imm8 which gets sign-extended to 64-bit.  So yes, if you need to move RSP by only 8, one dummy `push` is generally cheaper, especially if that avoids a [stack-sync uop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture) (if you can avoid all explicit uses of RSP before the next push/pop/call/ret).  If you need to move it farther than 8, usually sub is best (or `add $-128, %rsp` which is still 4 bytes).  Unless you can be pushing useful data as you go, like initializers for locals.

Comment: In my compiler, I am using both methods. simple push works for places like function internal code where I can keep a stack count. Aligning the stack works for function entry where stack accounting is more difficult.

Comment: Ok, if your compiler internals aren't yet to the point where you can deal with the initial "count" being odd, e.g. including the already-allocated return address, then yeah you could just always set up RBP as a frame pointer so you can restore RSP after an `and` changes it by an amount you don't try to calculate.  But note that `push rbp` aligns the stack so you don't need to `and` at that point, only if you do an unknown number of pushes, or a variable-sized allocation.

Comment: I should have explained that (but how much do you really want to know about my code). The compiler is fairly linear (it makes expression trees but does not graph the full routine). It allocates temps on the stack, and you don't know what that is before the routine is finished, so there is no way to know the even/odd status of allocation unless you make all of them even (one possibility). So that unconditional allocation worked out.

Comment: This does not apply to out/downcalls because the stack depth is metered, and you know what it is anywhere within the routine.

Comment: So you're starting code-gen before you finish compiling the whole function?  You could [do what TCC does and fill in a placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737690/tiny-c-compilers-generated-code-emits-extra-unnecessary-nops-and-jmps) `sub rsp, imm` with whatever size once you get to the end of the function and have seen all the places that use stack space for temporaries and whether they can overlap.  And after rounding the size up to a multiple of 8, and checking that you'll get RSP to a 16-byte boundary

Comment: Maybe somethings not that simple for some reason, but `and rsp, -16` seems silly and should be easy to avoid except as part of allocating something with runtime-variable size.  (Or in that case round up the allocation size instead of temporarily having an RSP that might not even be aligned by 8.)