# Segmentation fault when using printf in nasm 64bit

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, printf, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to call printf in nasm 64 bit linux. But it outputs segmentation fault when i run it. I alligned the stack, add a 0 escape character to the end of the string. But it still output segfault.

The code:

```
section .data
_DATA1 db "aa", 0

section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
sub rsp, 16
lea r13, [_DATA1]
mov rdi, r13
call printf
add rsp, 16
mov rax, 0
ret
```

assemble and link with

```
nasm -f elf64 a.asm
gcc -no-pie a.o
```

Where did i do something wrong?

Comment: To align the stack you'd have to use `sub rsp, 8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it.
It turns out i need to add after `main` :

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
```

So the code looks like this:

```
section .data
_DATA1 db "aa", 0

section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 16
lea r13, [_DATA1]
mov rdi, r13
call printf
add rsp, 16
mov rax, 0
mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret
```

I realise that this is also what gcc do

Comment: Moving RSP to RBP isn't the reason.

Comment: Does printf care about stack alignment even with AL=0 in current builds of glibc?  Scanf has for a while: [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716)

Comment: @MichaelPetch well, idk but somehow, it magically works...

Comment: I could understand it working if you also pushed RBP at the top and popped it before the ret

Comment: @michael ah yes, i do pushed rbp and popped it before ret. That's probably why.

Comment: That makes sense. Pushing an 8 byte value has the effect of subtracting 8 from RSP which aligned the stack. When `main` is initially called the  stack was 16 byte aligned but the call itself placed the 8 byte return address on the stack misaligning the stack by 8. To realign you'd have to subtract 8, 24, 40 etc

Comment: You should have been able to get it to work without the push and use of rbp altogether by subtracting 8 from RSP in our original question.