# why stack overflow attacks (modifying the returning address of a function call) caused segmentation fault in `_int_malloc`

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, function-call, stack-smash

I'm learning the structure of stack frames. And trying to implement a function that can call another function without an explicit call in C by modifying the returning address (in its stack frame) of the function call.

The code is like the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void malfunc() {
    puts("hello world");
    exit(0);
}

void set_arr() {
    size_t a[2];
    a[0] = 114;
    a[1] = 514;
    a[3] = (size_t)malfunc;
    // a[3] points to the position of returning address in stack frame
}

int main() {
    set_arr();
    return 0;
}
```

In my expectation, the string `hello world` should be printed because the returning address of `set_arr` is modified to `malfunc()` by the assignment `a[3] = (size_t)malfunc`.

The stack frame for `set_arr()` should look like:

```
a[0]
------------------------------------
a[1]
------------------------------------
previous base pointer (rbp of main)  <--- current rbp, a[2]
------------------------------------
original return address (main)       <--- a[3], modified to malfunc
```

This code worked perfectly in Compiler Explorer, the link is [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:17,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:17,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:17,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:17,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+malfunc()+%7B%0A%09puts(%22hello+world%22)%3B%0A%09exit(0)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+set_arr()+%7B%0A%09size_t+a%5B2%5D%3B%0A%09a%5B0%5D+%3D+114%3B%0A%09a%5B1%5D+%3D+514%3B%0A%09a%5B3%5D+%3D+(size_t)malfunc%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%09set_arr()%3B%0A%09return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.74973307708735,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-g3%27,selection:(endColumn:15,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:15,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:15,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:15,startLineNumber:9),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:32.91693358957934,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

However, if I compile this code locally with the following compile options

```
gcc stk_ov.c -o stk_ov -fno-stack-protector -ggdb3
```

and run the code, a segmentation fault will be thrown.

And if I use gdb to catch the segmentation fault, I get the following output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e2d540 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7fa2c80 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=640) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4375
4375    ./malloc/malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7e2d540 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7fa2c80 <main_arena>, 
    bytes=bytes@entry=640) at ./malloc/malloc.c:4375
#1  0x00007ffff7e2da49 in tcache_init () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3245
#2  0x00007ffff7e2e25e in tcache_init () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3241
#3  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3306
#4  0x00007ffff7e07c24 in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (
    fp=0x7ffff7fa3780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at ./libio/filedoalloc.c:101
#5  0x00007ffff7e16d60 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (
    fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7fa3780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#6  0x00007ffff7e15fe0 in _IO_new_file_overflow (
    f=0x7ffff7fa3780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, ch=-1) at ./libio/fileops.c:744
#7  0x00007ffff7e14755 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (n=11, data=<optimized out>, 
    f=<optimized out>) at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#8  _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7fa3780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, 
    n=11) at ./libio/fileops.c:1196
#9  0x00007ffff7e09f9c in __GI__IO_puts (str=0x555555556004 "hello world")
    at ./libio/libioP.h:947
#10 0x0000555555555180 in malfunc () at stk_ov.c:6
#11 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007ffff7db2d90 in __libc_start_call_main (
    main=main@entry=0x5555555551b0 <main>, argc=1, argc@entry=-11536, 
    argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffd408) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#13 0x00007ffff7db2e40 in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x5555555551b0 <main>, 
    argc=-11536, argv=0x7fffffffd408, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffd3f8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#14 0x00005555555550a5 in _start ()
```

However, if I pop the `rbp` register at the begging of `malfunc`, everything worked fine:

```c
void malfunc() {
    asm volatile("pop rbp");
    puts("hello world");
    exit(0);
}
```

```
malfunc:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        pop     rbp  ; newly added
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        mov     edi, 0
        call    exit
```

So I'm confused by the difference between these two and what caused this segmentation fault.

For the original version, after entered `malfunc`, the `rbp` register will be set to the stack pointer (`mov rbp, rsp`). But after I poped it, it stayed the same.

My environment is listed on the following, hope they will be useful:

- gcc version: `gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0`
- OS: Ubuntu-22.04 running on WSL2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `puts` in recent builds of glibc segfaults on a misaligned stack pointer, especially on the first call where it has to allocate some buffers.  Check what instruction faulted, it's probably `movaps` or `movdqa` to or from the stack, as in *[glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070716/glibc-scanf-segmentation-faults-when-called-from-a-function-that-doesnt-align-r)*

(Update: thanks to Nate for confirming the segfault is on a [`movaps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movaps) inside `malloc`.)

---

GCC code-gen for `malfunc` of course assumes it will be entered with `RSP % 16 == 8` from `call` pushing a return address (in a caller that has `RSP % 16 == 0` before a `call`, as required/guaranteed by the ABI).  But returning from a function will restore `RSP % 16 == 0`, so you're violating the ABI if that return address is the top of a function.

One workaround could be to inject a second return address, so you initially return to a `ret` instruction anywhere (doing `rsp-=8` to get there), and that `ret` does another `rsp-=8` while popping `malfunc` into RIP.

Or much simpler, instead of returning to the top of `malfunc`, return to the instruction *after* its `push rbp`.  You don't need it to return to anywhere, so that push was useless.  So is the `mov rbp, rsp` in this case; it doesn't deref RBP before making the function call you want.  The RBP value is irrelevant, all that matters is **RSP** being an odd or even multiple of 8, i.e. how it's aligned relative to a 16-byte boundary.

So you can actually skip the whole prologue, and just overwrite the return address with the address of the `mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0` instruction.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed stack alignment; I was just about to post.  It's a `movaps %xmm1, 0x10(%rsp)` inside of `malloc`.