# Exiting with a weird exit code, and SIGSEGV on attempting to exit with 0 in .s file

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to learn how to use `.s` files, and wrote the following:

```
    .globl main
    .text

main:
    mov $msg, %rdi
    call puts

    ret

    .data
msg:
    .asciz "Hello, world!"
```

I then compile with the following:

```
$ gcc -no-pie -c -o example.o example.s
$ gcc -no-pie -o example example.s
```

The `example` executable produced prints `Hello, world!` as expected, but exits with exit code `14`, suggesting that something went wrong regarding the print?

I tried exiting manually like so:

```
    .globl main
    .text

main:
    mov $msg, %rdi
    call puts

    mov 0, %rdi
    call exit

    ret

    .data
msg:
    .asciz "Hello, world!"
```

However, this segfaulted. From `gdb`, it seems to segfault on the line `mov 0, %rdi`, however I've tried multiple ways of moving (`movq 0, %edi`, `movl 0, %edi`, `mov 0x0, %rdi`) and all have segfaulted.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In the first program, before the `ret` instruction, set `%rax` to zero. This is equivalent to `return 0;` in a C program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah I see, it's in `%rax`? I just tried `mov 0, %rax` but this segfaulted as well? Am I moving immediates into registers wrong?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah whoops, that was a typo - In my actual code, `ret` is after `exit`. Just fixed that ^^

Comment: By the way, if you're wondering what the exit code `14` comes from, it just happens to be what [`puts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) returned (because that's what happens to be in `%rax` when you invoke the `ret` instruction).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah gotcha, that makes sense - I thought `ret`'s exit code would be in `%rdi` like function arguments.

Comment: What resource have you used to learn that the first argument should be in `%rdi`? Didn't it say that the returned value should be in `%rax`?

Comment: Try `mov $0, %rax`.  Without a dollar sign, the number is interpreted as an absolute address; you are effectively dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: You're lucky `puts` itself didn't fault; [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716)