# Is the stack aligned before the call?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

quick question: is the stack aligned before calling `atoi` in this piece of code?

```
         global  main
         extern  atoi
         default rel

         section .text
main:    push    rdi
         push    rsi
         mov     rdi, [rsi]
         call    atoi
         mov     rdi, rax
         mov     rsi, 1
         mov     rax, 1
         syscall
         pop     rsi
         pop     rdi
         xor     rax, rax
         ret
```

Comment: That code misaligns the stack.  The change in RSP needs to be an *odd* multiple of 8, from function entry to running a `call`.  See [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716) for details about the ABI requirement / guarantee that `rsp % 16 == 8` at the top of a function.  (`_start` isn't a function, but you have a `main` that's called normally by CRT startup code).  Try it yourself in a debugger like GDB and `p /x $rsp` when stopped before the `call` instruction, and then `si` into the `call`.

Comment: @PeterCordes so `rsp` is misaligned since entering `main`, since `main` itself, as it is a function, must have been `call`ed from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  That's also why it's possible to `ret` from `main`.

Comment: In some environments, the operating system transfers control to `_start`, which calls `main`.  This means that `main` is a function that can return to its caller whereas `_start` cannot as there isn't any caller — so it needs to use a syscall some form of `_exit()`.