# Trying to get two numbers from the user, and keep them in the stack and print them from the stack in assembly

Tags: assembly, char, x86-64

I have been trying to write a program in assembly where I get two numbers that I will later pass on as chars, save them in the stack, then get them out of there one by one and print them.
I get the numbers this way - "%c %c" - and I can't seem to get both numbers, only the first, and the second thing it gets is the \n.
I will mention that I use *printf* and *scanf* in this program.

So far I have `subq $8, %rsp`, and put each number there. Then I'm trying to print the numbers but instead, it prints only the second number and the \n. I think that each time I `subq $8, %rsp` it's enough for the char, and I do give *printf* the right addresses, but it doesn't save what I want it to save, maybe you can show me how to save them in the stack with *printf*?

Thank you for your help in advance.

This is how I saved them so far:

```
    movq $scanf_c, %rdi
    subq $8, %rsp
    movq %rsp, %rsi
    subq $8, %rsp
    movq %rsp, %rdx
    call scanf
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If that doesn't segfault from stack misalignment ([glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716)), that should be equivalent to calling scanf correctly from C with `scanf("%c %c", &c1, &c2)`.  If `%c` and a space in the format string don't do what you wanted, maybe don't use scanf; its rules for whitespace are tricky (*[scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789)*).  But that should work for one input line like `5 6`.

Comment: Have you checked with a debugger to verify the characters in memory, so you can be sure that's what you actually got for input, rather than some other bug in how you printed them out?

Comment: That scanf call with that format string works for me in a C program.  Add a [mcve] of how you ran this and the actual format string you used, and the input you typed into your program.